# How to change location of <script> element tags in an angular-cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Normally when building a project with the Angular CLI the script tags get added directly before the closing body tag.

Is it possible to move the script tags to a different location?

Currently I'm using webpack to control the location of the script tags, but is there a way to do this with the Angular CLI?

Answer (score 0):

There is no property in the official wiki page of Angular Cli to control the location of the script tags generated, see:
[Angular CLI Config Schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli)